# How EF knew what table in SQL Server the DBContext class should bind to

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently starting ASP.NET MVC 4 and in the book I am reading, EF was used. We were doing a sample project and we created a Products table in localdb. After creating the table, we created a DbContext-derived class. Here is the class:

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

and a repository that uses this:

```
public class EFProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
    public IQueryable<Product> Products
    {
        get { return context.Products; }
    }
}
```

Now on the MVC project, we added this line in the connectionstring

```
<add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=SportsStore;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And when project was run, content of Products table was loaded in browser. My questions are:

1. How did EF knew what database to use? I'm guessing the EFDbContext name in connection string corresponds to the EFDbContext class as changing the name produces no output. But how were they "connected" to each other? EF automatically does this based on name?
2. How did EF knew what table to get data from? Initially, I thought it was based on name of table (Products) which should be the same as property name, but I tried renaming property to some other name (I tried naming it XXX) but still the data was displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You already answered your first question, EF uses convention over configuration. EF uses the connection string name that matches with the class name of your DbContext class.

To answer #2, EF uses "Product" as shown below to name the table, and this is how it knows what table to get the date from as well. The name you use in your code can be anything like "SomeRandonName" and that does not change anything as that is mapped to the table named Product.

```
public DbSet<Product> SomeRandomName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, one question though. My table name is Products with an 's', how did EF know to map to DbSet<Product> (my product class is without 's')? Is this a convention of EF too?